# Using Zip files in Forge

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

Hey I need to know which files to extract if any to put a mod with a zip file into my minecraft game. I need to know if i extract the folders that are in the zip file or anything else? Thanks.

Comment: sorry SevenSidedDie But thats not what i need.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have forge installed right, you need to drop the zip file (unextracted) into your mods folder. It does depend on the mod a little bit, so follow the particular installation instructions of the mod you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You usually can just put the .zip file into the /mods folder. If the mod doesn't load properly, than unzip the file and look for a .jar file. If all else fails, look at the mod's READ-ME file or the mod's web page.